# Is it a bad practice to re-GET list data after a successful item DELETE?

Tags: javascript, http, http-get, http-delete

If my client-side application displays a list of items requested from my API, and a user deletes an item, is it best practice to then again call the list GET  at the end of the successful HTTP DELETE promise and update the view? Or should the application state simply be updated locally after the delete, without hitting the API again?

I understand optimistically updating your application, but, that is more for view update performance rather than reducing server calls.

Comment: Is it a bad performance practice? Yes. Is it a bad practice? Depends. Sometimes it is OK to trade off performance for other improvements. e.g. security.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make another GET request to update the list if the list data may change without user interaction, eg: server-side updates, or another session that can change the same list

With the performance aspect, let the user see the entry deleted ASAP, then very shortly after they will see the updated changes (if there are any), and it won't disturb them.

If there is a deletion error, refresh the updated list regardless

EDIT: I'd also suggest using websockets